# What does servlets-default.jar do?

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, servlets

Application is moved by Tomcat5.0. 
There will be an error if `servlets-default.jar` is contained in the application:

```
HTTP Status 404 - Servlet default is not available
```

However, when deleting `servlets-default.jar` out of application, it moved normally.

What does `servlets-default.jar` do?

---

Thank you　nowaq！
Thank you  Piotr Nowicki!
I'm user874235.

> > need more info, where did you get servlets-default.jar from?

⇒Sorry.This Application is very old.
 It is not understood where servlets-default.jar　was obtained. 
 However, I think that it probably obtained out of Tomcat. 
 (Incidentally servlets-default.jar’ｓ size is 19K.)

> > he jar contains just a couple of files. The most important one is DefaultServlet.class.

⇒It seems that it is used in application, extending DefaultServlet.class when it checks.

Comment: need more info, where did you get servlets-default.jar from?

Answer (score 0):

The jar contains just a couple of files. The most important one is `DefaultServlet.class`. `DefaultServlet` is the default resource-serving servlet for most web applications, used to serve static resources such as HTML pages and images.

Take a look at [the source files](http://www.google.com/codesearch#RP9-mFsAT-A/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.java&q=file%3aDefaultServlet.java&type=cs) and they will tell you all.